# wpf nested databinding for listboxes and listitems

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, data-binding

I'm new to WPF and databinding. I need to bind expander header to a List(Of Names) and expander content to a List(Of Services). I'm even more confused after reading MS tutorials on databindings (how and where to use staticResource, Path, etc.)

I have a

```
-------------
class Person 

name as string 
List servies as List (Of Services)

end class
--------------
class Service

name as string 
end class
----------------
```

In my main class Application.vb i have a list of Person objects

```
p1 as List(of Person)
```

I initialize all of them to dummy values.
in Application.xaml, I have

```
<Expander Name="listBox4" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
 HorizontalAlignment="Left" Header="   {Binding}" Content="{Binding}" >

  <Expander.HeaderTemplate >

      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
      </DataTemplate>

   </Expander.HeaderTemplate> 

   <Expander.ContentTemplate>

      <DataTemplate >
        <ListBoxItem Content="{Binding}"/> 
      </DataTemplate>

    </Expander.ContentTemplate>                 

</Expander >
```

How do I bind header textblock to the person name and the inner listbox item to their services ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are working with a List of objects, you need to use an `ItemsControl`. Expanders can only deal with one DataContext, while ItemsControls were meant to work with Lists or Collections

Your code should look something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Expander Header="{Binding Name}">
                <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Services}" />
            </Expander>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

This creates a loop that says go through the PersonList and for each Person it generates an Expander with the Header equal to the Person's name and the Expanded Content equal to a ListBox which displays all of that Person's Services.

Comment: i can't refer to the variables in my Application.vb, how to i call them here, 
or is there a way to do this programmatically by only having the {Binding} in the XAML?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. Whatever container holds the `ItemsControl` should have its `DataContext` set to your List of People. For example, you could put `Me.MainWindow.DataContext = p1` in your MainWindow's loaded event. Once your DataContext is set, you can access any property of that DataContext, so if your DataContext is a Person object, you can bind to `Person.Name` using `{Binding Name}`, or `Person.Services` by `{Binding Services}`

Comment: hey, thanks! im just about getting the hand of what is DataContext is. I did what you said and overrode the toString methods and it worked!

A followup, question, i put all this stuff in a <grid Name="grid1">. can we have multiple data contexts for this grid?

Comment: No, a Grid can only have one DataContext at a time. You can set different DataContext's for each of the Grid's child controls though, and you can reference properties outside of your DataContext through `RelativeSource` or `ElementName` bindings